# Is there a way to reduce the resolution of xarray facetgrid plots?

Tags: python, python-xarray, facet-grid

When plotting a single xarray I can use something like: `ds['variable'][::5,::5].plot()` to reduce the lat and lon resolution by a factor of 5. Is there a similar way to reduce the resolution when using facet grids?

e.g., I'm currently plotting: `WL_monthly.plot(x='lon',y='lat',col='time',col_wrap=4)`
but due to the high resoultion of the data it takes a couple of minutes to plot.

I tried: `WL_monthly[::5,::5].plot(x='lon',y='lat',col='time',col_wrap=4)`
but this slices the array's time entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When slicing positionally like this, the slice arguments are interpreted in the order of the array's dimensions. So you can inspect `WL_monthly.dims` to see the dimension ordering and then slice accordingly.

For example, if your array has dimensions `(time, lat, lon)`, you could plot using:

```py
WL_monthly[:, ::5,::5].plot(x='lon',y='lat',col='time',col_wrap=4)
```

You can also slice using named dimensions using `.sel` or using `.loc`, which allows you to specify dims using a dictionary and slice with a python `slice` object, e.g.:

```py
# using .sel()
WL_monthly.sel(lat=slice(None, None, 5), lon=slice(None, None, 5))

# using .loc[]
WL_monthly.loc[{'lat': slice(None, None, 5), 'lon': slice(None, None, 5)}]
```

This is admittedly a bit clunky. The xarray docs on [indexing and selecting data](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#indexing-with-dimension-names) summarize the situation well:

> We would love to be able to do indexing with labeled dimension names inside brackets, but unfortunately, Python [does yet not support](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0472/) indexing with keyword arguments like `da[space=0]`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I'm sorry for the late response, I was meaning to say thanks earlier.